# Unsubscribe email using Fetch api Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, fetch

I have a form where i enter an email and it gets ''subscribed'' in a user.json file using a fetch api on node server.My task is to :

- upon clicking on the "Unsubscribe" button, implement the functionality for unsubscribing from the community list. For that, make POST Ajax request using http://localhost:3000/unsubscribe endpoint.

I tried to make the function but it wasnt succeseful so i deleted it.  Also,i need to do the following :

- While the requests to http://localhost:3000/subscribe and
  http://localhost:3000/unsubscribe endpoints are in progress, prevent
  additional requests upon clicking on "Subscribe" and "Unsubscribe".
  Also, disable them (use the disabled attribute) and style them using
  opacity: 0.5.
  For me ajax requests,fetch and javascript is something new,so i dont know really well how to do this task,if you could help me i'll be happy,thanks in advance.

**fetch code for subscribing:**

```
 import { validateEmail } from './email-validator.js'

export const sendSubscribe = (emailInput) => {
    const isValidEmail = validateEmail(emailInput)
    if (isValidEmail === true) {
        sendData(emailInput);
    }
}

export const sendHttpRequest = (method, url, data) => {
    return fetch(url, {
        method: method,
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: data ? {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        } : {}
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
            return response.json().then(errResData => {
                const error = new Error('Something went wrong!');
                error.data = errResData;
                throw error;
            });
        }
        return response.json();
    });
};

const sendData = (emailInput) => {
    sendHttpRequest('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/subscribe', {
        email: emailInput
    }).then(responseData => {
        return responseData
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err, err.data);
        window.alert(err.data.error)
    });
}
```

**index.js from route node server:**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const FileStorage = require('../services/FileStorage');

/* POST /subscribe */
router.post('/subscribe', async function (req, res) {
  try {
    if (!req.body || !req.body.email) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Wrong payload" });
    }

    if (req.body.email === 'forbidden@gmail.com') {
      return res.status(422).json({ error: "Email is already in use" });
    }

    const data = {email: req.body.email};
    await FileStorage.writeFile('user.json', data);
    await res.json({success: true})
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500).send('Internal error');
  }
});

/* GET /unsubscribe */
router.post('/unsubscribe ', async function (req, res) {
  try {
    await FileStorage.deleteFile('user.json');
    await FileStorage.writeFile('user-analytics.json', []);
    await FileStorage.writeFile('performance-analytics.json', []);
    await res.json({success: true})
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(500).send('Internal error');
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

And user.json file looks like this :

```
{"email":"Email@gmail.com"}
```

**This is my attempt for unsubscribing :**

```
export const unsubscribeUser = () => {
    try {
        const response =  fetch('http://localhost:8080/unsubscribe', {
          method: "POST"
        });
      
        if (!response.ok) {
          const message = 'Error with Status Code: ' + response.status;
          throw new Error(message);
        }
      
        const data =  response.json();
        console.log(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + error);
      }
}
```

It gives the following errors:

```
Error: Error: Error with Status Code: undefined
main.js:2 
main.js:2 POST http://localhost:8080/unsubscribe 404 (Not Found)
```

**FileStorage.js:**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fsp = fs.promises;

class FileStorage {
  static getRealPath(path) {
    return `${global.appRoot}/storage/${path}`
  }

  static async checkFileExist(path, mode = fs.constants.F_OK) {
    try {
      await fsp.access(FileStorage.getRealPath(path), mode);
      return true
    } catch (e) {
      return false
    }
  }

  static async readFile(path) {
    if (await FileStorage.checkFileExist(path)) {
      return await fsp.readFile(FileStorage.getRealPath(path), 'utf-8');
    } else {
      throw new Error('File read error');
    }
  }

  static async readJsonFile(path) {
    const rawJson = await FileStorage.readFile(path);
    try {
      return JSON.parse(rawJson);
    } catch (e) {
      return {error: 'Non valid JSON in file content'};
    }
  }

  static async writeFile(path, content) {
    const preparedContent = typeof content !== 'string' && typeof content === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(content) : content;
    return await fsp.writeFile(FileStorage.getRealPath(path), preparedContent);
  }

  static async deleteFile(path) {
    if (!await FileStorage.checkFileExist(path, fs.constants.F_OK | fs.constants.W_OK)) {
      return await fsp.unlink(FileStorage.getRealPath(path));
    }
    return true;
  }

}

module.exports = FileStorage;
```

Comment: I feel its not that hard,but information on internet about this isnt so much..

Comment: 404 resource not found means endpoint is unreachable. Try restarting your server if your code changes aren't auto updated. Also make sure your port numbers match up.

Comment: I restarted the server,,checked the numbers,everything is good,i dont understand why it doesnt want to make this post request..

Comment: I don't see any obvious issues, try reusing the same function you used to make subscribe request. `sendHttpRequest('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/subscribe')`. In general try to copy every little thing you're doing with subscribe.

Comment: Wooooooooooooooooooooow,it was error in the route,an extra space... router.post('/unsubscribe ',  < was like that...

Comment: Happens to best of us.  Good tip is if everything makes too much sense to not be working, check the small details. And if all else fells, if you have something you know works that you can copy and paste, do that.

Comment: I will,thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using a database for handling CRUD operations on your persisted data. If you must use filestorage, theres a flat file DB library called [lowdb](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb) that can make working the files easier.

As for preventing duplicate requests, you can track if user has already made a request.

```js
let fetchBtn = document.getElementById('fetch')
let isFetching = false

fetchBtn.addEventListener('click', handleClick)

async function handleClick(){
  if (isFetching) return // do nothing if request already made
  isFetching = true
  disableBtn()
  const response = await fetchMock()
  isFetching = false
  enableBtn()
}

function fetchMock(){
    // const response = await fetch("https://example.com");
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout (() => resolve('hello'), 2000))
}

function disableBtn(){
  fetchBtn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  fetchBtn.style.opacity = "0.5"
}
function enableBtn(){
  fetchBtn.removeAttribute('disabled');
  fetchBtn.style.opacity = "1"
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="fetch">Fetch</button>
```

Comment: The task is for mastering ajax requests and use this node server,i can not use anything else :(

Comment: that sucks, what does your Filestorage.js service file look like.

Comment: i added in the question

Comment: I added code to disable button in my answer.

Comment: Thank you ! I try to make this post for unsubscribing after that i try the code for button <3